# Mongoose Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, es6-promise

I'm trying to setup (this is my first attempt) a function that receives input, passes it through a function, then the results of that through a follow up.

I'm getting the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined
```

I've never used Promises before and I believe that's what I should be doing in this instance, I don't think I'm quite understanding how to structure things with the .exec and .then parts.

```
app.get('/api/gameobjects/:userid/:golng/:golat/:dist', (req, res) =>
{
    console.log("First part");
    GameObject.getNearGameObjects(req.params.golng, req.params.golat, req.params.dist)
    .exec((err, gameobject) =>
    {
        if (err)
        {
            res.json(err);
        }
    })
    .then((gameobject) =>
    {
        console.log("Third part");
        User.addGameObjectToUser(req.params.userid, gameobject)
    })
});
```

EDIT:
Code for the getNearGameObjects:

```
// Get Near Game Objects
module.exports.getNearGameObjects = function( long, lat, dist, callback, limit )
{
    var coords = [];
    coords[ 0 ] = long;
    coords[ 1 ] = lat;

    var query =
    { geometry: { $near: { "$geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [long, lat] }, $maxDistance: dist } } };

    GameObject.find( query, callback ).limit( limit );
};
```

Code for the addGameObjectToUser

```
// Add object to user
module.exports.addGameObjectToUser = function(id, gameobject, callback)
{
    var query = { _id: id };
    User.findByIdAndUpdate( query, { "$addToSet" : { "inventory" : gameobject } } );
};
```

Comment: Can you post `getNearGameObjects()` body?

Comment: Added the code to the original post.

Comment: I've since tried rewriting the code following a tutorial on Mongoose promise code, but I'm still getting the same error or a similar one. All of the examples I've seen don't use the same API call setup to there examples so I have to make some assumptions of what to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't return anything from the function, by default it returns `undefined`

You're getting

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined

because `.exec()` will be called on the returned `undefined`.

If you want to call `.exec()` on the `find()`, you should remove callback parameter on it. So that it returns `promise`

Making those changes,

```
module.exports.getNearGameObjects = function (long, lat, dist, callback, limit) {
  return GameObject.find({
    geometry: {
      $near: {
        "$geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [long, lat]
        },
        $maxDistance: dist
      }
    }
  }).limit(limit);
};
```

Similarly, `.catch()` will handle error when it occurs.

```
GameObject.getNearGameObjects(req.params.golng, req.params.golat, req.params.dist)
  .exec().then((gameobject) => {
  console.log('Third part');
  return User.addGameObjectToUser(req.params.userid, gameobject);
}).catch((err) => {
  res.json(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go back to the code I know and nested by called based on result, this means more code, but more importantly it works.

I'd still be very interested in understanding how to do promise based code in the API, as it does look like it would be a tidier format to work with.

Here's the working code:

```
app.get('/api/gameobjects/:userid/:golng/:golat/:dist', function (req, res)
{
    console.log("starting");
    GameObject.getNearGameObject(req.params.golng, req.params.golat, req.params.dist, function (err, gameobject)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            res.json(err);
        }
        console.log("got a game object");
        User.addGameObjectToUser(req.params.userid, gameobject, function (err, user)
        {
            if (err)
            {
                res.json(err);
            }
            console.log("updated a user");
            GameObject.removeGameObjectByLocation(req.params.golng, req.params.golat, function(err, gameobject)
            {
                if (err)
                {
                    res.json(err);
                }
                console.log("removed a game object");
                res.json(gameobject);
            });
        });
    });
});
```